# C each time i try to excute the program it repeat the input twice

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<windows.h>
typedef int tab[20];
int Size,Operation;
void SaisirNombreComptes(void)
{
    printf("Merci davoir saisir le nombre des comptes bancaire: ");scanf("%i",&Size);
}

void SaisirComptesEtSoldes(tab TabComptes, tab TabSoldes, int Size)
{
    for(int i=1;i<=Size;i++)
    {
        printf("donner le numero du compte %i: ",i);scanf("%i",&TabComptes[i]);

        printf("saisir l& solde du compte {%i} TND: ",TabComptes[i]);scanf("%i",&TabSoldes[i]);
    }
}

void AfficherComptesInfo(tab TabComptes, tab TabSoldes, int Size)
{

    printf("Tableau des comptes");

    printf("\n");

    for(int i=1;i<=Size;i++)
    {
        printf("[%i]",TabComptes[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");


    printf("Tableau des Soldes");

    printf("\n");

    for(int i=1;i<=Size;i++)
    {
        printf("[%i]",TabSoldes[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    printf("\n");
}

int RechercherComptePos(tab TabComptes, int Size, int x)
{
    int i=1;
    int Pos;

    while( (i<=Size) && (TabComptes[i] != x) )
    {
        i+=1;
    }

    if(i<=Size)
        Pos = i;
    else
        Pos = -1;
    return Pos;
}

void AjouterCompte(tab TabComptes, tab TabSoldes, int *Size, int Compte, int Montant)
{
    *Size = *Size + 1;
    TabComptes[*Size] = Compte;
    TabSoldes[*Size] = Montant;
}

void SupprimerCompte(tab TabComptes, tab TabSoldes, int *Size, int Compte)
{
    int ComptePos = RechercherComptePos(TabComptes,*Size,Compte);

    for(int i=ComptePos;i<=*Size;i++)
    {
        TabComptes[i] = TabComptes[i+1];
        TabSoldes[i] = TabSoldes[i+1];
    }

    *Size = *Size - 1;

}

void DesposerSoldes(tab TabComptes, tab TabSoldes, int Size, int Compte, int Montant)
{
    int ComptePos = RechercherComptePos(TabComptes,Size,Compte);

    TabSoldes[ComptePos]+=Montant;
}

void RetirerSoldes(tab TabComptes, tab TabSoldes, int Size, int Compte, int Montant)
{
    int ComptePos = RechercherComptePos(TabComptes,Size,Compte);

    TabSoldes[ComptePos]-=Montant;
}

void TransfererSoldes(tab TabComptes, tab TabSoldes,int Size,int Compte1, int Compte2, int Montant)
{
    int Transferer = RechercherComptePos(TabComptes,Size,Compte1);

    int Recevoir = RechercherComptePos(TabComptes,Size,Compte2);

    if(TabSoldes[Transferer]>=Montant)
    {
        TabSoldes[Transferer] -= Montant;

        TabSoldes[Recevoir] += Montant;
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Operation echoue, solde insuffisante");
    }
}

void Menu(void)
{
    system("cls");
    printf("\n\nChoisir un Operation a faire :\n1:Ajouter un Compte:\n2:Supprimer un Compte\n3:Desposer un Solde\n4:Retirer un solde\n5:Transfer un montant\n6:Afficher les information du compte\nTaper quelque touche pour quitter" );
    scanf("%i",&Operation);
}


int main()
{
    tab TabSoldes,TabComptes;

    int NumCompte,Montant,NumCompte1,NumCompte2,i;

    bool encore = true;

    char AfficheMenu;

    i = 0;

    SaisirNombreComptes();

    SaisirComptesEtSoldes(TabComptes,TabSoldes,Size);

    Menu();

    while(encore == true)
    {
        switch(*Operation)
        {
            case 1:
                printf("Donner le numero du compte a ajouter :");scanf("%i",&NumCompte);
                printf("Donner le Montant");scanf("%i",&Montant);
                AjouterCompte(TabComptes,TabSoldes,&Size,NumCompte,Montant);
                printf("Voulez-vous voir le menu Taper 'O' pour OUI 'N' pour NON");scanf("%c",&AfficheMenu);
                if((AfficheMenu=='O') || (AfficheMenu=='o'))
                {
                    Menu();
                }
                else if(AfficheMenu=='N' || AfficheMenu=='n')
                    encore = false;
                else
                    printf("error");
            break;

            case 2:
                printf("Donner le numero du compte a supprimer :");scanf("%i",&NumCompte);
                SupprimerCompte(TabComptes,TabSoldes,&Size,NumCompte);
                printf("Voulez-vous voir le menu Taper 'O' pour OUI 'N' pour NON");scanf("%c",&AfficheMenu);
                if((AfficheMenu == 'O') || (AfficheMenu == 'o'))
                {
                    Menu();
                }
                else if(AfficheMenu == 'N' || AfficheMenu =='n')
                    encore = false;
                else
                    printf("error");
            break;

            case 3:
                printf("Donner le numero du compte pour desposer d'argent: ");scanf("%i",&NumCompte);
                printf("Donner le montant: ");scanf("%i",&Montant);
                DesposerSoldes(TabComptes,TabSoldes,Size,NumCompte,Montant);
                printf("Voulez-vous voir le menu Taper 'O' pour OUI 'N' pour NON");scanf("%c",&AfficheMenu);
                if((AfficheMenu == 'O') || (AfficheMenu == 'o'))
                {
                    Menu();
                }
                else if(AfficheMenu == 'N' || AfficheMenu =='n')
                    encore = false;
                else
                    printf("error");
            break;

            case 4:
                printf("Donner le numero du compte pour retirer d'argent: ");scanf("%i",&NumCompte);
                printf("Donner le montant: ");scanf("%i",&Montant);
                RetirerSoldes(TabComptes,TabSoldes,Size,NumCompte,Montant);
                printf("Voulez-vous voir le menu Taper 'O' pour OUI 'N' pour NON");scanf("%c",&AfficheMenu);
                if((AfficheMenu == 'O') || (AfficheMenu == 'o'))
                {
                    Menu();
                }
                else if(AfficheMenu == 'N' || AfficheMenu =='n')
                    encore = false;
                else
                    printf("error");
            break;

            case 5:
                printf("Donner le numero du compte: ");scanf("%i",&NumCompte1);
                printf("Donner le numero du compte destinaire: ");scanf("%i",&NumCompte2);
                printf("Donner le montant a transferer");scanf("%i",&Montant);
                TransfererSoldes(TabComptes,TabSoldes,Size,NumCompte1,NumCompte2,Montant);
                printf("Voulez-vous voir le menu Taper 'O' pour OUI 'N' our NON");scanf("%c",&AfficheMenu);
                if((AfficheMenu == 'O') || (AfficheMenu == 'o'))
                {
                    Menu();
                }
                else if(AfficheMenu == 'N' || AfficheMenu =='n')
                    encore = false;
                else
                    printf("error");
            break;

            case 6: 
                AfficherComptesInfo(TabComptes,TabSoldes,Size);
                printf("Voulez-vous voir le menu Taper 'O' pour OUI 'N' our NON");scanf("%c",&AfficheMenu);
                if((AfficheMenu == 'O') || (AfficheMenu == 'o'))
                {
                    Menu();
                }
                else if(AfficheMenu == 'N' || AfficheMenu =='n')
                    encore = false;
                else
                    printf("error");
            break;
        }
        i=i+1;
        printf("\n%i\n",i);
    }
}
```

This program correct in syntaxe but there a probleme in excution mode (Output) when i try for exemple to add an account number it adds it twice in the table Consider we have two tables.

TabAccounts:[112566][256325][122662]

TabMoney   :[ 200$ ][ 400$ ][ 257$ ]

So if i choose from the menu "1" : wihch mean add an account with montant it will add the account and montant twice like this for exemple:letssay i wanna add another account with number of 10066854 and montant 300$ it will output like this

TabAccounts:[112566][256325][122662][10066854 ][10066854 ]

TabMoney   :[ 200$ ][ 400$ ][ 257$ ][   300$  ][   300$  ]

if anyone can help i will apperciate that i spend 3 days looking for the problem

Comment: In C, indices go from `0..n-1`, so your for loops should be `for(int i=0;i<Size;i++)`

Comment: @user3121023 #user3121023 Thanks it worked i apperciate that

Comment: @user3121023 You seem to have found the answer, at least to the question asked. Please turn it into an official answer, I want this out of the list of unanswered questions. For a good answer, I propose to ask Paul for permission to also use his contribution.

Comment: @user3121023  Thanks it worked i apperciate that

Comment: @PaulOgilvie Would you mind, of your contribution from comment would be used in an  answer? I assume not, but if so, please use the hammer to get rid of this unanswered question... (I assume a dupe is why you did not make an answer.)

Comment: @MhennaouiMohamed Saying thanks on StackOverflow is usually expressed by accepting an answer. For that you need to get the commenter to make the answer you can accept. Otherwise you can create your own answer, detailing the combination of comments which helped you. Giving credit in that answer is also a very accepted way of saying thanks.

Comment: @Yunnosch today is my first day in stackoverflow i dont know much about this site to be honest or how to use it im sorry i just found it when i was searching for solution to my problem still new here

Comment: It is fine, you are doing great. I just recommend adressing a comment at user3121023, to motivate them to write an answer you can accept.

Comment: I noticed in your code multiple istances of what I dare to call an anti pattern: `printf("request"); scanf("%...", &...);` in the *same line of code*. I'd suggest to write a proper function (or more than one) which would print a message, asking for a particular value, and then *check* the input for its validity (at least the value returned by `scanf`), looping if necessary.

Comment: thanks @Bob__ i will work on that do you have any other sugesstion that can optimize my code ?